# Is there a way to highlight a specific word in terminal?

Tags: command-line, syntax-highlighting

I am using two switches that are very similar and I would like to colour each switch in a different colour.
So that any time that I will write in the command line that word - it will automatic highlight it..
Is it possible?

Comment: Not in bash. Zsh can do syntax highlighting, but [the most common plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) highlights commands, not options.